# How to detect a relational database design defects

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, relational-database

What kind of tools (most interested in SQL Server) are there to automate process of database refactoring, specifically, detect possible defects in design (like absence of primary keys or primary keys on string columns or table with too much columns or even assumptions about violation of normal forms, although this kind of stuff depends on business domain)?

Overall, which kind of defects in database design may be and which of them can be detected by tools?

Comment: Better post it in dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The absence of primary keys can easily be found using sys.objects.

There's nothing wrong with primary keys based on string columns.
You might mix it with the recommendations for a clustered index design...

There's no definition of "Too many columns" other than the database limit (e.g. 1024 columns per nonwide table). It all depends on the business case.

An indication of normal form violation can be done either by analyzing the metadata (e.g. looking for similar column names like Name_1, Name_2, Name_3) or by analyzing the data itself (e.g. searching for multiple comma in a column that might indicate a list stored in a column). Both methods can and usually will lead to a result set being incomplete and at the same time missing some violations. Therefore, it's just a "hint"...

Comment: yes, off course, all such 'violations' are just hints, same with number of columns (for ex. having 50 column does not always mean a design defect, but if somebody wants any hints about possible design defects then it's worth pointing out)